# How to enter content to an existing CSV file

Tags: visual-foxpro

I am trying to enter data cell by cell to a CSV file, but when I open it, I get all the contents in column A of the CSV file separated by "," (comma).

I am trying it in the following way:

```
oExcel = CREATEOBJECT("Excel.Application")
oWorkBook=oExcel.Workbooks.Open("c:\planilla.csv")
oExcel.application.Cells(1,1).Value = "StockCode"
oExcel.application.Cells(1,2).Value = "In-Stock"
oExcel.application.Cells(1,3).Value = "Kit"
oWorkbook.Save()
oWorkbook.Close()
oExcel.Quit()

RELEASE oWorkbook
RELEASE oExcel
```

When opening the CSV document, the output is in a single cell (column A), like this:
`StockCode, In-Stock, Kit.`

I hope you can help me, regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, I don't understand why you are trying to use the Excel object in order to create a csv file. Why don't you just create a csv file with the commands in VFP?

Second, I did try your example and it did create one cell with the 3 items separated by 2 tabs. But, if I do the same thing on an xlsx file (an actual Excel workbook), your example works. I don't think the Excel office automation object was ever intended to be used on a CSV file.

If you need to output to a CSV file, you can do that with VFP commands without having to create an Excel object.

Saw your comment... try running this in VFP:

```
* create cursor and some records
CREATE CURSOR test (nid i, stockcode c(10),instock i,kit c(20), lincsv l)
INSERT INTO test (nid,stockcode,instock,kit,lincsv) VALUES (1,"SC-001",10,"kit001",.f.)
INSERT INTO test (nid,stockcode,instock,kit,lincsv) VALUES (2,"SC-010",0,"kit003",.f.)
INSERT INTO test (nid,stockcode,instock,kit,lincsv) VALUES (3,"SC-200",5,"kit010",.f.)
* call function to add records to csv file
=AddToCSV()
* insert a couple more records to cursor
INSERT INTO test (nid,stockcode,instock,kit,lincsv) VALUES (4,"SC-201",6,"kit001",.f.)
INSERT INTO test (nid,stockcode,instock,kit,lincsv) VALUES (5,"SC-005",520,"kit099",.f.)
* call function again to add new records to existing csv file
=AddToCSV()

FUNCTION AddToCSV
* open csv file (create if it doesn't exist, add to existing)
SET ALTERNATE TO c:\temp\planilla.csv ADDITIVE 
SET ALTERNATE ON 
SCAN FOR NOT linCSV
    ?? stockcode + ","
    ?? instock
    ?? "," + kit
    replace lincsv WITH .t.
    ?
ENDSCAN
SET ALTERNATE OFF 
SET ALTERNATE TO 
RETURN
```

Comment: thanks for answering but i need to insert data to existing csv file and not create it

Comment: It is still not necessary to use Excel automation to do this. You can append to an existing CSV file. Much easier.

Comment: Pecyma You can put an example, it is that I am new, I have only been in this language this week

Comment: It's Pecyna, but calling me Ed is easier! :)